# What license(s) are the Android support libraries released under?

Tags: android

I've been reading through the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) for the Android Support Library, but while it explicitly says that you should include it in your Android project, it doesn't mention anything about what license the library itself is under (the only license notice present applies to the contents of the documentation page, not the code it describes). The copy spat out by Eclipse does not include any licensing information either, and queries to Google mostly just link back to the same documentation pages.

This confuses me. Should I include a notice that the code is from Google? Not put in any license notice at all? Or am I not properly understanding how the library is meant to be used? Admittedly, I am quite new to Android development.

Comment: +1 for effort and writing a coherent question.

Comment: I've created a feature request to include license information in the standard location: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=235923

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Each source file, (like [this one](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v13/java/android/support/v13/app/FragmentCompat.java)) contains a copyright header like this:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2011 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
```

Which states an Apache license:

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

And, I think apache license allows derivative works to be built and sold. Still, you should:

1. Include same license in source of the derived product as well.
2. Clearly state what parts you derived changes, built upon.

You can place this in `Licence.txt` or `Readme.txt` at the root of your project.

Comment: [Useful info about the license.](http://www.tldrlegal.com/license/apache-license-2.0-%28apache-2.0%29)

Comment: I double checked the license in the code as well and can confirm that it's Apache-2.0.

Answer (score 5):

Look into your NOTICE.txt file in your android/support folder. Quote: "The Android Open Source Project. Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0, [...], http://www.apache.org/licenses/".

Comment: Useful, although I initially did not know which folder you were referring to. For any future readers, it's android-sdk-root-folder/extras/android/support/

Answer (score 3):

Look at this file (Local Maven repository for Support Libraries is subset of this path):

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/maven_repo/android/+/master/NOTICE.txt

> **Notice for all the files in this folder.**
>
> …
>
> Copyright (c) 2005-2013, The Android Open Source Project
>
> …
>
> Apache License Version 2.0, January 2004
>
> …