# Android Support Library and Firebase SDK license attribution

Tags: android, firebase, android-support-library

I am creating, inside an Android app, the page within the "about" section that lists all the used third party libraries together with their license.
Should I mention the Android Support Library as well? And what about the Firebase SDK?
Please, if possible, include a source to support your answer.. also, I am aware that there are a few libraries that try to accomplish this job automatically: I am not interested in those, I have tried them and they are not good enough for me.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase is part of Google Play Services, and that previously required you to use the following method call to get the license text [GoogleApiAvailability.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability#getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(android.content.Context))

But you can see from the javadoc for that method, it's no longer required to add to your app.

The Android support library is distributed under the well-known Apache 2.0 license, so you just need to follow its rules.  [See this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257729/what-licenses-are-the-android-support-libraries-released-under).